# react-scripts start fails with import error, but react-scripts build succeeds

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, react-scripts

When running `react-scripts start`, I get an import error for a couple files relating to default imports:

```
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'Quote' is not exported from './Quote' (imported as 'Quote').

ERROR in ./src/PageOne.tsx 103:41-46
export 'Quote' (imported as 'Quote') was not found in './Quote' (possible exports: default)

ERROR in ./src/PageTwo.tsx 165:49-60
export 'InlineQuote' (imported as 'InlineQuote') was not found in './Quote' (possible exports: default)

webpack compiled with 2 errors
No issues found.
```

But if I run `react-scripts build`, it compiles just fine with no errors.

Quote and InlineQuote are both default exports from files located in the same directory, which are then re-exported by an index.ts file in that directory, as named exports instead of default.

A minimal example of the code in question:

`client/src/Quote/Quote.tsx`:

```
const Quote: React.FC = () => (<>implementation1</>);
export default Quote;
```

`client/src/Quote/InlineQuote.tsx`:

```
const InlineQuote: React.FC = () => (<>implementation2</>)
export default InlineQuote;
```

`client/src/Quote/index.ts`:

```
export { default as Quote } from './Quote';
export { default as InlineQuote } from './InlineQuote';
```

And then some files that import those components:

`client/src/PageOne.tsx`:

```
import { Quote } from './Quote';
// ...
```

`client/src/PageTwo.tsx`:

```
import { InlineQuote } from './Quote';
// ...
```

**Deleting `index.ts` and just importing directly from the components' files fixed this issue for me**, but I'm curious why it happened in the first place.

Was this export/import code actually wrong? But if it's wrong, then why did it not break `react-scripts build`?

Answer (score 0):

If you import your component with braces, you will only import the `export` components, not the `export default` (I think).

So try that :

`client/src/PageOne.tsx`:

```
import Quote from './Quote';
// ...
```

`client/src/PageTwo.tsx`:

```
import InlineQuote from './Quote';
// ...
```

*I'm not sure what I'm saying, if I'm not, please let me know, I'll delete my answer.*

Comment: I don't think this is it, because when index.ts does `export { default as Quote } from './Quote';`, it converts it from a default export to a named export